# Proper date formatting of string read from a SqlDataReader

Tags: c#, sql-server, date-formatting

I'm reading a Date field from a `SqlDataReader` and I want to write it to a label.

My code for this line looks like this:

```
lblTDate.Text = string.Format("{0:D}", (DT2(["TDate"].ToString()));
```

The label shows, for instance, "4/7/2016 12:00:00 AM" but I want it to show "Sunday, April 07, 2016".

I read on [this site](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/) that using `{0:D}` should do it, but it's not working.

The field in the SQL Server table is a `Date` field, not a `DateTime` field, which makes it all the more baffling that the time is showing up.  But, anyway, how can I get my label to show the date in the format I want to see?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
lblTDate.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(DT2["TDate"]).ToString("dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: I get an error.  "No overload for method ToString takes 2 arguments"

Comment: Did you really convert the value to a DateTime object first then?

Comment: Apologies, I missed one of the parenthesis.  Worked perfectly.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to convert the object that is returned from the [indexer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f01t4cfy(v=vs.110).aspx) to a string, before you hand it off to a String.Format. By leaving out the `ToString` call you would have got what you want.

```
lblTDate.Text = string.Format("{0:D}", DT2["TDate"]);
```

This enables the String.Format implementation to use [`IFormattable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformattable(v=vs.110).aspx) implementation of the DateTime type which makes that the format string you've found will work. Once it is a string there is no way for the String.Format implementation to know what to do.

Alternatively cast the value to the IFormattable interface, like so:

```
var fmt = DT2["creationdate"] as IFormattable;
if (fmt != null)
{
    lblTDate.Text = fmt.ToString(
        "dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy",
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```

but then you have to provide an IFormatProvider implementation, often in the form of an instance of a CultureInfo class.

Notice that in both of the above options, you don't have to to convert the value to a DateTime first.

Answer (score -2):

```
CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("en-Us");
DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi = culture.DateTimeFormat;

var myDate = new DateTime(2016, 7, 4, 12, 0, 0);

string month = culture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(dtfi.GetMonthName(myDate.Month));
string dayOfWeek = culture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(dtfi.GetDayName(myDate.DayOfWeek));
string fullDate = $"{dayOfWeek}, {month} {myDate.Day}, {myDate.Year}";

Console.Write(fullDate);
```